# Make Xcode build a C file generated by processing a file with a custom extension

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, c-preprocessor, build-rules

I'm trying to set up Xcode to build generated .c files just like it does for files generated by yacc (`*.y`) and lex (`*.l`) files.

Say I have input files with a `*.corn` extension that are meant to be processed by a tool of mine to create C source files. I then want these C source files to be compiled and linked using the rest of Xcode's mechanisms.

This is exactly what happens to my `.y` and `.l` files for `yacc` and `lex`. The project target contains only the `.y` and `.l` files and the rest happens automatically. Generated `.c` files get put in the derived files directory and those get compiled and linked automatically.

Here's what I've tried so far:

-If I just add a `.corn` file to my target, Xcode copies it into the bundle at build time presuming it is a resource. Okay, whatever.

-I then create a custom build rule to handle

**Source files with names matching:**  *.corn

**Using Custom Script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
cp "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" "${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.c"
```

I have to give it an output file so:

**OutputFiles:**
${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.c

Note in this case I'm just copying the file as I rename it with .c extension. (As I'm playing around, the .corn file just contains C source.)

So now *before* the bundle directory even gets created I get the following warning:

```
unexpected C compiler invocation with specified outputs: 'blahblahblah/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/foo.c' (for input: 'blahblahblah/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/DerivedSources/foo.c')
```

Then *after* the link phase (sheesh!), the script above runs and I do end up with my foo.c in DERIVED_FILES_DIR. It doesn't get compiled however and notably, foo.corn didn't get copied into the bundle anymore so there's hope.

I've tried a bunch of other stuff, but this is the cleanest I can describe that others can try. Please what is the magic incantation to make this work?!

Note that I've also tried using DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR instead of DERIVED_FILES_DIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I missed two things:

1. I needed to add the .corn files to the "Compile Sources" build phase.
2. By adding .corn files to the project/target before the adding the custom build rule, Xcode added the .corn files to the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase which broke the build.